# Uso del verbo "escalar" como sinónimo de "hacer escala"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, vocabulario-técnico, neologismos

Hace un par de días me encontré con el siguiente titular:

> [*Pullmantur escalará por primera vez en Cartagena este año.*](http://www.laopiniondemurcia.es/cartagena/2018/05/28/pullmantur-escalara-primera-vez-ciudad/925693.html)

**Me chocó el uso del verbo [*escalar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G6T25Xg|G6TYQPC), pues ninguna de las acepciones recogidas en el DLE le dan el significado de *hacer escala***, que es la locución usada habitualmente en estos casos.

De hecho, tengo bastante claro que el uso de *escalar* en la forma en que lo hace el titular es, si no incorrecto, sí al menos "novedoso". Pero no es esa mi pregunta.

Volviendo a la locución *hacer escala*, consultando el DLE vemos que se basa en la etimología de 'escala' como 'puerto':

> [**escala**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G67txjD#RjPRbfW)
>   <sub>Del lat. *scala* 'escalera'; en aceps. 8 y 9, del it. *scala*, y este del gr. bizant. σκάλα *skála* 'puerto'.</sub>
>
> 8. f. Parada que efectúa una embarcación o una aeronave entre su punto de origen y el de destino. *La escala en Lisboa se alargó más de lo previsto.*
> 9. f. Lugar donde tocan las embarcaciones o las aeronaves entre su punto de origen y el de destino.

De aquí la locución *hacer escala* como "hacer parada un barco o aeronave".

Entiendo, pues, que el razonamiento de quien escribió el titular fue que, **de igual manera que decimos "parar" en lugar de "hacer parada", se puede decir "escalar" en lugar de "hacer escala"**.

Mis preguntas:

- DLE aparte, **¿sería correcto el razonamiento indicado?** ¿Se puede aplicar en cualquier caso?
- **¿Está establecido este uso de 'escalar' en campos específicos** (agencias de viajes, turismo, gestión de aerolíneas...)? ¿O ha sido más bien una ocurrencia del autor de la noticia?

Comment: Nunca había oído decir *escalar* para *hacer escala*, yo diría que es un error del periodista pero a lo mejor me confundo y su uso está más extendido de lo que imagino, no sería la primera vez que me pasa

Comment: El razonamiento es impecable, la palabra no sé; está claro el sentido pero no recuerdo haberla visto así en ninguna parte. Siguiendo esa idea muy bien podríamos decir que los barcos *aportan* (llegan a puerto).

Comment: Yo tampoco lo había oído en mi vida ni creo que suene bien (al menos en España). Y, a modo de curiosidad, _aportar_ existe en gallego con el significado que indica @pablodf76.

Comment: Tampoco me suena bien (al menos para México). Yo diría "Pullmantur _parará/visitará/llegará/arribará_ por primera vez en Cartagena este año."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con respecto a tu primera pregunta (¿es adecuado el razonamiento indicado?), sostengo que sí. Ese, de hecho, es un fenómeno ampliamente estudiado en el mundo de la academia hispanista: la **formación de nuevas palabras por derivación**.<sup>1</sup> Específicamente, el ejemplo que citas es una **verbalización denominal causativa**, <sup>2</sup> cuya paráfrasis explicativa es: "hacer, decir, convertir X o como X".<sup>3</sup>

Otros ejemplos de este tipo de verbalización (más usados y conocidos) son:

- Amalgamar (hacer amalgamas).
- Carbonar (hacer carbón o convertir en carbón).
- Brindar (hacer un brindis).
- Bizcochar (cocer el pan como un bizcocho, es decir, dos veces).
- Alcahuetar (hacer de alcahuete).
- Carrancear (mexicanismo; sinónimo de robar. "Hacer como Carranza", appellido de un ex presidente mexicano y líder revolucionario, famoso por permitir abusos de poder por parte de sus soldados durante la Revolución Mexicana).

Así, `escalar` (en el sentido que se le da en el titular: hacer una escala) efectivamente **no figura dentro de las acepciones reconocidas de la palabra**, pero estamos ante **un neologismo que se ajusta a un proceso de formación de palabras específico, previamente estudiado y documentado en la lengua española**.

Desafortunadamente, no tengo experiencia en el medio turístico o similares para responder tu segunda pregunta, pero espero haber contribuido en algo :)

---

<sup>1</sup> M. Alvar Esquerra, *La formación de palabras en español*, Arco/Libros, Madrid, 2<sup>a</sup> ed., 1995; y G. Guerrero Ramos, *Neologismos en el español actual*, Arco/Libros, Madrid, 1995.

<sup>2</sup> J.L. Cifuentes y R.M. Lavalde, "Sobre verbos denominales: construcciones causativas y de localización", *Quaderns de Filologia Estudis lingüístics*, 14 (2009), pp. 57-75.

<sup>3</sup> *Loc. cit.*

Comment: Es adecuado en el mismo sentido en que es adecuado el razonamiento del niño que dice "No sabo" (en vez de "no sé").  :)  El error de razonamiento no está en pensar que se puede derivar un verbo de un sustantivo, sino en pensar que se lo puede hacer en todos los casos, aunque nadie más lo haga, y aunque el resultado sea un verbo que ya tiene otro significado.

Answer (score -2):

Gracias por el razonamiento tan extenso, sin embargo tal como indicas usar `escalar` como sinónimo de `hacer escala` me parece un error gramatical del autor de la nota de prensa.

El origen de `hacer escala` o `escala` para una embarcación que atraca temporalmente en un puerto para continuar después su camino, parece ser el hecho de tener que soltar la escala (escalera naval simple de madera y cuerda) para que el personal desembarcara o abordara de vuelta la embarcación.

Sin embargo la acción y el significado del verbo `escalar` está muy bien definido y no se debería usar en el caso descrito de la pregunta.

Aunque siempre se podría decir: Embarqué escalando una vieja escala de cuerda durante nuestra escala en Lisboa.

Comment: Cuando se hacían (o se hacen) escalas en puertos para repostar o subir o bajar pasajeros muchas veces resulta poco práctico o económico atracar en un puerto, por lo que se tira la escala y se usa un bote para llegar a tierra mientras la embarcación principal se queda fondeada cerca de la bocana del puerto o abrigada en una bahía con playa.
Skála en griego no significa puerto, sino escalera o punto de atraque, justamente donde necesitas tirar una pasarela o una escalera para subir al barco:)